# Drupal drush install

Tags: php, drupal, drush

Any idea how resolve this issues :

vendor/bin/drush site-install $APP_PROFILE install_configure_form.enable_update_status_emails=NULL --db-prefix="es_" --account-name=$APP_ADMIN_USER --account-pass=$APP_ADMIN_PASSWORD --locale=fr -y --existing-config

#27 {main}
AssertionError: The '$prefix' argument to Drupal\Core\Database\Connection::setPrefix() must be a string in assert() (line 394 of /var/www/html/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php).
[warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.

php-fpm 8.2 and Drupal 9

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 9 does not support PHP 8.2 or is it the other way around.

As per the official documentation;
https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/system-requirements/php-requirements

Try dropping to PHP 8.1 and see if that helps.